# Multi-Step Aggregation in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How does one, in Pandas, do a multi-step / sequential aggregation on the same dataset?  As if each step is a "subquery" of the next.

I can think of it in SQL like this:

```
SELECT x.A, COUNT(x.B) as B_COUNT, SUM(x.C_SUM) as C_SUM
FROM (
    SELECT df.A, df.B, SUM(df.C) as C_SUM
    FROM df
    GROUP BY df.A, df.B
) x
GROUP BY x.A
```

Working in Python3.4 and Pandas0.19.2, I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas
import numpy

numpy.random.seed(1)
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                          'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                          'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C' : numpy.random.randn(8),
                   'D' : numpy.random.randn(8)})
```

I've tried aggregating to the A, B level and then working on that dataframe (i.e. then but it's index is 'C' and column 'A' throws a KeyError since it's not in the list of keys.

```
A_B_AGG = df.groupby(['A','B']).C.sum().to_frame()
A_B_AGG.keys()
#Index(['C'], dtype='object')
#Would like to do this, but throws KeyError
end_result = A_B_AGG.groupby('A').B.size()
```

Ultimately, I should get something that looks like...

```
A    B_COUNT      C_SUM
bar        3  -3.986264
foo        3   2.945186
```

Thank you for any guidance on the proper, pandas way of doing this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `agg` function:

```
df.groupby('A').agg({'B': pandas.Series.nunique, 'C': 'sum'})

#               C   B
#A      
#bar    -3.986264   3
#foo     2.945186   3
```

The reason I think this is equivalent to your SQL query is that when you do group by column A and B, then there will be no duplicates of B in each A group. So the count of B grouped by A will be the same as unique count of B grouped by A; For the C `sum`, sum of subgroups is the same as total sum for the groups.

---

This is a direct translation of your sql query, which I think logically equivalent to the above method:

```
(df.groupby(['A', 'B']).C.sum().reset_index()
   .groupby('A').agg({'B': 'count', 'C': 'sum'}))

#               C   B
# A     
#bar    -3.986264   3
#foo     2.945186   3
```

Comment: When you do `C.sum()` what happens to other columns? What happens to `D` Column? Can you aggregate few column and leave others when you do groupby?

Comment: @MYGz they are ignored. when you do `groupby(...).C` means you selected the column `C` along with group variables.

Comment: Thanks! So we have to use `.agg()` if we want different kind of aggregation on different columns right?

Comment: Yes. That is how you can apply different aggregation methods to different columns.

Comment: @Psidom this is it!  Thank you!